# How to Split response from Json in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I got response like "100.0" from server which I have to split to "100" and save in variable.How can I do that kindly tell me .

Comment: You can parse this as a string, convert the string to a double, and then cast the double to an integer

Comment: @Nitin: String [ ]value=wallet_balance.split(".");
then,
  access value[0]. you will get 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to parse your JSON response. Store your wallet balance in a String, them trim the value as per your request

```
 JSONObject object =  new JSONObject(JsonResponseText);
 String walletBal = object.getString("wallet balance");
 String trimWalletBal = walletBal.subString(0,walletBal.indexOf('.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
Integer value = jsonObject.getDouble("parameter").intValue();
```

Comment: I am getting that value as string :"wallet balance":"100.0"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your problem is just to split the "Integer" and "Fraction" part of a "string" value you are getting from the server -

```
int decimalIdx = stringVal.indexOf('.');
if (decIdx != -1) {
  return stringVal.substring(0, decIdx);
}
return stringVal;
```